# How to make Compass Vertical Rhythm output Rems instead of Ems with px fallback?

Tags: html, css, sass, compass-sass, mixins

I want to do this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ls3Clk-kz3s but output rems (with px fallback) instead of ems.

Apparently this https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/pull/896 is added to compass and should somehow work, but I don't quite get what do I need from http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/typography/vertical_rhythm/ to my .scss -file to make it.

If I were to just take the code from https://gist.github.com/ry5n/2026666 as a mixin (even without Compass at all) and use:

```
@include set-font-size()
```

instead of:

```
@include adjust-font-size-to()
```

It works beautifully with rem values and px fallback.

But if I just try to use Compass and go with

```
$font-unit: 1rem;
$relative-font-sizing: false;
```

It works but without px fallback.

If someone could put the full .scss code needed for Vertical Rhythm to work with Rems, I'd appreciate it very much.

And why do I need $relative-font-sizing: false if I'm using Rems?
Also, are there some competing philosophies on vertical rhythm other than getting the text to a grid like this? Which one do you prefer and what is your workflow?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the moment, these updates to Compass remain in the pre-release gem, and the matching documentation isn’t yet available on compass-style.org (not even beta.compass-style.org). To use the new features, install the latest gem (0.13.alpha.4):

```
gem install compass --pre
```

With the new gem, the vertical rhythm API is slightly different, mostly in its configurable variables, as per https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/pull/896. In short, set your base font size and line height, and set the new $rhythm-unit variable to `rem`:

```
$base-font-size: 16px;
$base-line-height: 24px;
$rhythm-unit: 'rem';
```

The $rhythm-unit variable replaces $font-unit, and $relative-font-sizing is now a private, internal thing you don’t need to worry about.

After this, all the normal vertical rhythm mixins will output rems with fallbacks (unless you explicitly set $rem-with-px-fallback to `false`). Note that the rest of the API remains nearly identical, with the exception of the `rhythm` mixin, which now has more sensible default arguments. There are a few additions which are detailed in the [original pull request](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/pull/896).

One thing to keep in mind that the rhythm functions can’t provide pixel fallbacks, since they simply return a value.

Comment: Thank you very much ry5n. For much needed feature to Compass and also a detailed answer. I'm using CodeKit myself, so it will probably update itself and Compass when new release comes out (any idea when?). But does your last sentence mean that in the new Compass release there won't be pixel fallbacks like https://gist.github.com/ry5n/2026666 has?

Comment: When compass 0.13 is released (I’m not sure when), you’ll have pixel fallbacks for all of the vertical rhythm mixins, like `adjust-font-size-to`, `leader`, `trailer`, `leading-border` and so on. The only thing you don’t get pixel fallbacks for are the *functions*, of which `rhythm()` is the only one I really use. Since these simply compute rhythm values (not output CSS), they can’t provide pixel fallbacks.

Comment: By the way, it is possible to tell CodeKit to use a local gem rather than the built-in Compass. See:

http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/can-you-use-compass-gems-with-codekit/#post-115282

http://incident57.com/codekit/help.php#help-compass

Comment: My CodeKit is now using Compass version 0.13.alpha.4, but still it still won't work unless I use the pull 896 -mixin. 
This is my .scss that still outputs ems:

`@import "compass";`

`$base-font-size: 18px;`
`$base-line-height: 24px;`
`$rhythm-unit: 'rem';`
`@include establish-baseline;`

I wonder if it's still usign older Compass somehow? When I click About on CodeKit it says it's now using that pre-installe version though.

Comment: Can the `@import compass` be a problem? Should the `@import` point to the pre-install version or should it be enough that CodeKit is using the pre-install version? Or should I start a new Compass project..?